# Application error when running angular app on heroku

Tags: javascript, angular, heroku, npm

I've successfully deployed my angular2 application to heroku but unfortunately I'm getting the **"An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served"** page displaying.

When I run the app locally using `npm start` it runs fine.

I think it may be something to do with dependencies or the heroku instance having a different configuration. I've tried modifying the start command but to no avail.

The project is built on the angular quickstart guide found [here](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html)

**My package.json file**

```
{
  "name": "danoram-angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run lite",
    "lite": "lite-server"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.3.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.3.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.16",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-rc.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0"
  }
}
```

**heroku logs**

```
2016-12-20T05:55:10.169815+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the danoram-angular-quickstart@1.0.0 lite script 'lite-server'.
2016-12-20T05:55:10.170077+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2016-12-20T05:55:10.170162+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the danoram-angular-quickstart package,
2016-12-20T05:55:10.170243+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-12-20T05:55:10.170321+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-12-20T05:55:10.170401+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     lite-server
2016-12-20T05:55:10.170464+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2016-12-20T05:55:10.170538+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs danoram-angular-quickstart
2016-12-20T05:55:10.170618+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2016-12-20T05:55:10.170696+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls danoram-angular-quickstart
2016-12-20T05:55:10.170790+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-12-20T05:55:10.173933+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-12-20T05:55:10.174095+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-12-20T05:55:10.174171+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-12-20T05:55:10.183775+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-12-20T05:55:10.191217+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-105-generic
2016-12-20T05:55:10.191388+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-12-20T05:55:10.191531+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.9.1
2016-12-20T05:55:10.191647+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
2016-12-20T05:55:10.191761+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-12-20T05:55:10.191855+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! danoram-angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `npm run lite`
2016-12-20T05:55:10.191943+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

I've also put the project code on github for reference [here](https://github.com/DanielOram/danoram-angular-quickstart)

All help is appreciated!

Comment: error is coming because `lite-server` is not installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't deploy an app to heroku without a backend. Your best choice of backend with an `angular2` app would be `nodejs`/`express` framework in my opinion.

Heroku will look at your package.json's start script which should be something like:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  }
```

My suggestion would be to wrap your project inside a folder (lets say **client** folder), then in the new root dir, create another **package.json** and an **app.js** file

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "basictemplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "web.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "heroku-prebuild": "echo This runs before Heroku installs your dependencies.",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm install --prefix ./client"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.13.3",
    "express": "^4.13.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "4.1.1"
  }
}
```

**app.js**:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}) );

app.use( express.static(__dirname + '/client' ) );

var listener = server.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, function(){
    console.log('Listening on port ' + listener.address().port); //Listening on port 5000
});
```

More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs

Comment: Thanks so much @echonax ! this has really helped my understanding too :D

Comment: I made an edit to your solution just to add a listener to the port. works like a charm

Comment: @Danoram Ah, thank you. I forgot that part :) and glad I could help.

Comment: can I run it with `ng serve` instead?